# Spring integration add route during runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is it possible to add route in Spring Integration during execution? I'm doing project in Spring Boot and I need to use Spring Integration to make routes able to create during runtime. I can't find proper example or documentation that describes is it possible and how to to that.

Comment: Please provide more details about the routes you want to add. Refer the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251125/3503019

Comment: Do you mean you want to route incoming requests to some other endpoints dynamically?

Comment: Did you try to get registered services from the registry then create your routes dynamically with it ?

Answer (score 1):

What is `route` in your mind? Are you really referring to the router component? Why then dynamic routers doesn’t work for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/message-routing.html#dynamic-routers?

So, you can populate router mappings at runtime using an `AbstractMappingMessageRouter`.

Since some version, we don’t require initial mapping any more.

If you speak about something what we call flows, then you need to take a look into Java DSL and it dynamic flows registration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows